# remove DotNet in BC 19

Tags: asp.net, dynamics-business-central

I want to get rid of the DotNet.

Are there any Codeunits I can use for this code (Maybe something in the FileManagement):

```
procedure GetNoOfFilesInFolder(): Integer
var
    DirectoryInfo: DotNet DirectoryInfo;
    Directory: DotNet Directory;
begin
    IF NOT Directory.Exists(pathToFolder) THEN
        EXIT(-1);
    DirectoryInfo := DirectoryInfo.DirectoryInfo(pathToFolder);
    EXIT(DirectoryInfo.GetFiles().Length);
end;
```

Comment: Which target are you compiling for? Cloud or OnPrem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use the `File Management` codeunit for that, however it only removes the direct DotNet dependency. `File Management` is just a wrapper around the very same DotNet assemblies.

Under all circumstances if you are to work with the file system you are required to set `target` to `OnPrem` in your `app.json`.

The following code should accomplish the same as your example:

```
local procedure GetNoOfFilesInFolder(PathToFolder: Text): Integer
var
    FileList: Record "Name/Value Buffer" temporary;
    FileManagement: Codeunit "File Management";
begin
    if not FileManagement.ServerDirectoryExists(PathToFolder) then
        exit(-1);

    FileManagement.GetServerDirectoryFilesList(FileList, PathToFolder);
    exit(FileList.Count);
end;
```